# PC crashes after connecting and activating the second monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors

After connecting a second monitor, it activates briefly before causing my PC to crash. The fans continue to spin and the RGB remains on, but the display, audio, and connection cut off. Upon restarting the computer, Windows repairs and begins to boot, but crashes again after a few seconds. i checkt the PSU its should be fine and i should have room to breath. something i found out today is that it only craches if it displays 2 monitors, right now i have both connectet but only displaying one.

PSU:Masterwatt Lite 600W 230V
GPU:RX590+
CPU:ryzen 5 2600
Maiboard:MSI B450M

Answer (score 0):

I have Windows 8.1 dual boot with Linux. I had a windows update today, turns out its my last one (end of product support), went ahead and installed it, afterwards if I connect a monitor to either the hdmi or displayport of my laptop, screen goes black, windows crashes. windows  works fine if i dont connect a second screen

## 2nd screen Works fine on linux.
no special monitors or refresh, no gaming etc, i just use 4k tv so i have a big work area

UPDATE - Either the last Windows 8.1 altered my BIOS setting, or something. Had to go into BIOS, enable Display port and something else, still didnt work, had to reload dell driver, then go back and get intel hd driver and update amd
driver, then after all that it worked again